# Saving OFT templates with MS Outlook

Tags: email, outlook

I have problem with saved MS Outlook template *.oft

I have simple HTML page with images (http://ukazky.kelocnet.cz/newsletter/), opened in Internet Explorer 9. With the function „*Send - page by email…*“ is the page inserted as new message into MS Outlook.

I have done three tests:

1) On my computer (Windows 7 64bit, MS Office 2010 32bit, IE8) I have created template *.oft and that cannot be opened.

2) On my coleg’s PC (Windows 7 64bit, MS Office 2007 32bit, IE10) I have created template *.oft and that cannot be opened too.

3) On third PC (Windows 7 64bit, MS Office 2007 32bit, IE9) I have created template *.oft and that is correctly opened.

All saved OFT templates is possible download here: http://ukazky.kelocnet.cz/newsletter/oft/oft.zip

**Resume**: When I save message as *.oft in case ad 1) and case ad 2), that message shows as blank in  MS Outlook and cannot be opened anywhere.

Notice: Look at the different sizes of *.oft files. Also I have tried save messages as *.msg and that cannot be opened anywhere too.

Do you have an Idea, where could by a problem? I need use this function on my PC.

Comment: How exactly did you create the OFT files?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko I have opened my simple HTML page in IE, then via _Send - page by email..._ create a new message in MS Outlook and here click _Save as_, then select OFT and Save.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem. There is two possible solutions:

1) Before *Save as OFT* in MS Outlook is neccessary *Save message* with Ctrl+S. Then you can save message as OFT and everything works fine.

2) Second solution is to send message to yourself and after that save message as OFT.